# Lodash ES6 import - why importing only some functions seems to import everything instead?

Tags: javascript, lodash, es6-module-loader

I'm trying this:

```
import { each,find,filter,map,some,debounce,defer,delay,throttle,uniq,assign,extend,merge,omit,without,findIndex,compact,replace,groupBy,max,uniqueId } from '../npm_components/node_modules/lodash/lodash';
```

The resulting file, seems to be the same size as for example I import only this:

```
import { delay } from '../npm_components/node_modules/lodash/lodash';
```

Why?

Comment: Because `import { x } from "y"` means *import all of "y" but just give me `x`*. It's essentially destructuring. You can import `lodash/delay` to just get that one.

Comment: ok thank you, if you want, add it as the answer

Comment: What do you mean by "*The resulting file*"? Are you bundling your modules? Are you using tree shaking?

Comment: I'm bundling, using codekit, exporting in UMD format, and via Babel.

Comment: If I want to use all those functions, what's the best way to import them? Importing all like `import lodash/delay` would be verbose in a file which contains othe spare code. I'm not so good in es6 modules usage. How would one do for keeping things tidy?